# How to avoid azure ad token in url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD, in which access token comes to teh redirect URL when the user is successfully signed in into their Microsoft account. Can we avoid getting this token in the URL, and get it somewhere else? Or is there any different approach required for this?

As if someone gets that token, they can hit the backend server of my application and can get data.

Comment: Are you talking about authorization code or the access token? AFAIK, access token (and other details come in response body).

Comment: i am talking about access token. It's coming in url section of browser.

Comment: What platform are you developing one? Can you please include the example code for how you're initiating the sign-in in your app?

Comment: I am using angular 7. In that, I have used microsoft Adal library, which is responsible for making user login into microsoft account and on successful sign in gives back a token.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6 . This is the library.

Comment: Is your concern that the user could grab the token and re-use it themselves against your backend service? Can you share an overview of how your backend service is doing token validation and authorization?

Comment: I have spring boot app as a backend, in which there is a package I have used for azure ad. In that there is a class AADAuthenticationFilter which validates and authenticates the user based on some properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is well-founded, but receiving a token in the redirect URI is central to how OAuth flows work, regardless of whether that's Azure AD or any other OAuth IdP.

From an [OAuth redirect URI overview](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/):

> Because the redirect URL will contain sensitive information, it is critical that the service doesn’t redirect the user to arbitrary locations.
>
> The best way to ensure the user will only be directed to appropriate locations is to require the developer to register one or more redirect URLs when they create the application.

You're redirecting them to a source you control, using an encrypted channel, and that's considered good enough for current Internet security operations.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. But my main concern is how should I ensure that the token is coming from my application or through some other medium(anyone who has the token can get data from backend server) ?

Comment: You don't. All you know is the token is for whoever signed in originally, and what scopes the token includes. If the app is a JavaScript application, remember that it's running in the user's browser already--you have no guarantee that the user isn't interfering with your client-side application anyway. What _is_ assumed to be true is that the redirect URL is only controlled by you, but it is up to the user and the user's browser to ensure the token doesn't go where it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, only the user can be authenticated in case of a public client app like this. The app cannot be authenticated.